# Android Gradle: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'

Tags: android, gradle

I downloaded an `Android` project from `github` by sunmi printer, to test my pos printer, but when start the build and `sync` the `project` it give me this `gradle error`:

> ERROR: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug, filters=[], versionCode=9, versionName=v2.7.2}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

Here the Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('../app/temp.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
        }
        debug {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('../app/temp.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.printertestdemop1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "v2.7.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all {
        variant ->
            variant.outputs.each {
                output -> output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "PrinterDemo_" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_P1.apk");
            }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    implementation 'com.sunmi:sunmiui:latest.release'
    implementation files('libs/core-3.3.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: comment out `android.applicationVariants.all` code block and it will be working fine. Issue is due to Gradle API changes, setter method on output file object is removed.

Comment: Set it as answer bro so i can add a positive feedback, it's worked!

Answer (score 0):

According to **[This reference](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html)**, output of variant doesn't provide setter method to set output file name. So it doesn't work with newer version of **Gradle API**.

**Solution:** you can use `setProperty()` method in defaultConfig block to set change base apk name something like,

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "your apk name here")
    ....
}
```